# NoSuchElementException, when method is called after code above it is run

Tags: java

When I run my code, it will run fine up to the line "scanner.close()".
After than, when I run the "SumTenNumbers()" method... it will run the first line of the while loop once and crash with the "NoSuchElementException"...
When I remove the code above the line calling the method, it runs fine...
Why does this occur, and how can I solve it?

This is the code:

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // we use the class "scanner" for input data
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //System.in allows you to type input data into the console which can be returned into the console
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your name is " + name);

        System.out.println("Enter your year of birth: ");
        boolean isInt = scanner.hasNextInt();
        if (isInt)
        {
            int yearOfBirth = scanner.nextInt();

            int age = 2019 - yearOfBirth;
            if (age >= 0 && age <= 120)
            {
                System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid year of birth");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to parse year of birth");
        }
        scanner.close(); // we must close scanner


        SumTenNumbers();



    }

    public static void SumTenNumbers()
    {
        var reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        int sum = 0;
        int count = 1;

        while (count < 11)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter number " + count + ": ");
            boolean valid = reader.hasNextInt();
            if (valid)
            {
                int userNum = reader.nextInt();
                sum += userNum;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                reader.next();
                System.out.println("INVALID");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sum);

        reader.close();
    }
}
```

This is how it looks when I run the code...

```
Enter your name: 
Siddharth
Your name is Siddharth
Enter your year of birth: 
2001
You are 18 years old
Enter number 1: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at com.company.Main.SumTenNumbers(Main.java:64)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:39)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: "we must close scanner" what makes you think so?

Comment: So in your case, put the close after SumTenNumbers, remove new and close from SumTenNumbers, make public static void SumTenNumbers(Scanner reader) and call SumTenNumbers(scanner);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line `reader.close()` closes the `Scanner` and, with it, `System.in`.

After that, you cannot read from `stdin` (`System.in`) anymore.

In order to prevent this you can:

- use only one `Scanner` object and close it after using it the last time
- close `System.in` after using it the last time (using a `Scanner` or `System.in.close())`
- close `System.in` at the end of your Program
- never close `System.in` (Problem: other Processes cannot use the resource, `stdin` can also be a File, a Network Connection or something else)

Comment: ah I understand. Thank you! I will implement this in my code